# Making a request and filtering records in controller before send out to endpoint

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have more then 8000 records in DB. I need a solid pagination and filtering functionality. To accomplish that I am trying to filter the records before paginate and send out those to endpoint.

For example in **controller** I request the `keyword` and check the `keyword` using `→when()` if there is keyword then filter records with that and `→paginate(20)`

in **controller**

```
public function bridal(Request $request)
{       

    $keyword = $request->get("keyword");

    $bridals = Place::with(["plans" => function($query)
        {
            $query->orderBy("plans.plan_price");
        } 
    ])
    ->whereHas("plans")
    ->groupBy("address")
    ->when($keyword, function($query, $keyword){
        return $query->where("city", $keyword);
    })
    ->paginate(20);

    return $bridals;

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::match(["GET", "POST"], "bridal", "Api\BridalController@bridal");
```

I guess everything is fine 'till here. So let's continue in **frontend** side.

in vuex: **Store.js**

```
state: {
    bridals: [],
    keyword: "",
},
mutations: {
    setBridals(state, bridal){
        state.bridals = bridal;
    },
    setKeywords(state, keys){
        state.keyword = keys;
    },
},
getters: {     
    getBridals(state){
        return state.bridals;
    },
},
actions: {
    bridalApi({commit}, payload){ 
        axios.get("api/bridal?page="+payload.page, {
            keyword: payload.forms.keyword
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.commit("setBridals", response.data);  
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        })
    },
}
```

and in **home** component I am sending filter params to controller.

```
 <form @submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
        <search-bar />
        <submit-btn />
 </form>


mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch("bridalApi", {
        page: this.currentPage,
        forms: this.filterParams,
    });
},
methods: {
    submit(){
        this.$store.dispatch("bridalApi", {
            forms: this.filterParams,
        });
    },
},  
computed: {                
    filterParams(){
        let paramObj = {
            keyword: this.$store.state.bridal.keyword,
        }

        return paramObj;          
    }
},
```

I am not sure what is wrong in the code. Where do I make mistake.

**P.S**: By the way I set and get the keyword `state.keyword`... it's working fine. I can get the value. I just didn't add input code here...

Comment: Instead of accessing state directly in the computed block, use getters like so: `this.$store.getters.bridals`.